# increment numbers in list comprehension

Tags: python, list, if-statement, increment, python-2.x

I am new to python. I am learning list comprehension to shorten my code to minimum. But I am unable to incremnent inside a list comprehension. Like this code:

```
n = 0; c = 0
for i in range(input()):
   m = map(int,raw_input().split())
   [n+=1 if m[0] > m[1] else c+=1]
print ['N', 'C'][c > n]
```

My input:

```
3
3 4
2 4
2 5
```

The output should be:

**N**

Comment: Are you using Python 2?

Comment: Is `['N'. 'C']` supposed to be `['N', 'C']`?

Comment: A list comprehension needs an iterable to loop over. You don't have a list comprehension, just a list with one value. You're also not assigning the list to a variable.

Comment: In this particular case, you could just use a generator expression in `sum` to calculate `n` (or `c`) and calculate the other with the difference from the total (the first input).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not actually need to keep track of both `n` and `c`, since you can calculate one from the other and the total (your first input).

```
t = input()
n = 0
for i in range(t):
   a, b = map(int, raw_input().split())
   n += (a > b)
print 'N' if n >= t/2 else 'C'
```

If you really want to make this shorter (note: except for Code Golf, shorter does not always mean better) you could try something like this:

```
t = input()
n = sum(1 for i in range(t) for a, b in [map(int, raw_input().split())] if a > b)
print 'N' if n >= t/2 else 'C'
```

Or without `t`, use [`cmp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#cmp) (retired in Python 3) to count `+1` for `a > b` and `-1` for `a < b`, then compare to `0`. But this will handle the case `a == b` differently, and the readability finally goes down the drain.

```
n = sum(cmp(*map(int, raw_input().split())) for _ in range(input()))
print 'N' if n >= 0 else 'C'
```

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions are for making lists.  You appear to want

```
if m[0] > m[1]: n+=1 
else: c+=1
```

This does not address the other errors in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The above code has multiple problems -

- We are not converting the `input()` to `int`
- We are using both `input()` and `raw_input()`
- List comprehension does not allow += operator

Comment: Python 2 knows both `input` and `raw_input`, where `input` automatically evaluates the string input, in this case to an integer.